# ReactiveUI sync ReactiveCommand invocation cause System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I try to bind simple synchronous command with ReactiveUI.

```
public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

public bool IsClicked;

public MainViewModel()
{
    ClickCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(OnClick);
}

private void OnClick()
{
    //just example of fast action   
    IsClicked = true;
}
```

But when I invoke it I get an error:

**System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread can not access this object, since the owner of this object is another thread**

In the invocation stack i can see it is about System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.UpdateCanExecute(). 
How can i avoid changes of ReactiveCommand.CanExecute or force it to invoke in the UI thread?

Comment: Does it work if you define the property like this? `public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ClickCommand { get; }`

Comment: I've seen this too many times. Definitely belongs in a FAQ section somewhere. Try adding the ReactveUI.WPF package to your project. It contains a number of WPF-related threading packages registered with ReactiveUI's dependency inversion system. If this solves your issue, I'll add it as an official answer.

Comment: @mm8 Doesn't change anything

Comment: @ColtBauman it helps! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish there were a better error message. Try adding the ReactiveUI.WPF package to your project. It contains a number of WPF-related threading packages registered with ReactiveUI's dependency inversion system. You'll also find this information in step 2 of the [getting started documentation](https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/). Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue for weeks. My exception was throw when a menu item was trying to update its state (the ReactiveCommand is bound to a menu item).

Adding `ReactiveUI.WPF` to the project solved the issue.